# CodenameOne GoogleConnect success callback is not triggered on Android

Tags: android, codenameone, google-plus-signin

I am trying to create a simple Google authentication example, but the login success callback is not triggered. Here is what I have done:

1. Added build hint `android.playService.auth`, `android.playService.auth` both set to true.
2. Created a developer certificate for android, and pasted SHA1 into Google Developer console Android client
3. In the Google developer console, enable Google Plus API.

Then I pasted the example code from here https://www.codenameone.com/google-login.html

But on the device, the successful login callback is not triggered after the first doLogin() call, only after the second.

Note that following similar steps I was able to configure Facebook auth and everything went fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here though.
How do I configure Google Authentication in Codename One?

Comment: Is this repeatable? Is so can you connect the device with a cable and see if you have any output in DDMS?

Comment: I tried to make a simple example, and again the callback is triggered only on the second doLogn(), note that I did not notice an error in the logs.

Comment: Can you change the api level to 21 and see if it works then? It might be related to the marshmallow migration.

Comment: See this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/switching-on-android-marshmallow-permission-prompts.html

Comment: Great! It worked! Write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a regression with the migration to API level 23 and the new Android permissions system the current workaround is to [revert to API level 21](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/switching-on-android-marshmallow-permission-prompts.html) but that poses a problem with apps already submitted to Google with level 23.

I've filed [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1961) to track the fix that should work for newer API levels.